# Custom ArrayAdapter NullpointerException

Tags: android, arraylist, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I got a problem with my Custom Array Adapter:

I have a `NullpointerException` in my `getView()` Method.

I already found out that the `ArrayList` seems not to be the problem because it works fine without the Adapter.

**My Adapter**

```
public class ArrayAdapterCusPostlist extends ArrayAdapter<Post> {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<Post> postListe;


    public ArrayAdapterCusPostlist(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Post>pList) {

        super(mContext, layoutResourceId, pList);
        postListe = pList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowpost, parent, false);
        }
        Post curpost=postListe.get(position);

        if(curpost!=null){
        TextView textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nickname2);
        textViewItem.setText(curpost.getName());
        textViewItem.setTag(curpost.getName());
        }

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

And: If the `ArrayList` is Empty because I did not called the `add()` Method there is no `NullPointerException`. Here is my Array List:

```
    ArrayList<Post> PostList=new ArrayList<Post>();
    PostList.add(new Post("Name", "Zeit", "Post", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.winter), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.winter)));
    mPostList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.postliste);
    final ArrayAdapterCusPostlist adapter2 = new ArrayAdapterCusPostlist(this, R.layout.rowpost, PostList);
    mPostList.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Context mContext;` is not initialized

```
 Context mContext;
 LayoutInflater inflater;
 public ArrayAdapterCusPostlist(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Post>pList) {
 super(mContext, layoutResourceId, pList);
 this.mContext =mContext;
 inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); // initialize here. no need for context initialization if you have this here.
 }
```

Also it is better you use a `ViewHolder` Pattern

```
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowpost, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nickname2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
          holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Post curpost=postListe.get(position);

     holder.textViewItem.setText(curpost.getName());
     holder.textViewItem.setTag(curpost.getName());
    }

    return convertView;

static class ViewHolder
{
     TextView textViewItem;
}
}
```